# Photoshop brush opacity is 50% despite being set to 100%

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, opacity

Whenever I try to make a brush stroke in Photoshop it comes out 50% transparent, even though:

- The brush opacity is set to 100%
- The layer is set to 100%
- The mode is normal.

I've reset the brush tool, but it didn't help at all.

I haven't changed anything, but it seems that somehow the brushes and the paintbucket are not working properly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'd comment but my rep is too low here. The way I read your question. It sounds to me as though the flow setting is set below 100%.

Comment: Is it feathering

Comment: There's a weird symbol between opacity and flow try pressing that

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot get it to wotk, you can reset *all* your Photoshop preferences by starting Photoshop with Ctrl+Alt+Shift held down (Command-Option-Shift on the Mac).

Comment: Occasionally this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new layer then adjusting the opacity of the layer. Its not the best way but always a good alternative.